# Plotting lines graduated based on a speed attribute

Tags: point, line

Is there a way of turning point data (ship vessel tracks.csv) into lines, whereby the lines inherit a attribute (speed)? I have tried points to one plugin which doesn't carry over any attributes from the original point data.

The goal is to show vessels operating at a set speeds e.g 0-4 not trawling, 4-6 trawling, >6 steaming as tracks(lines) with each speed category using a different coloured line.

The end shapefile would be a continuos line with different colors indicating the speed of the vessel.

Im using QGIS and ARCGIS so a solution for either platform would be great.

Comment: Which software are you using?